# error in encrypting image with RSA

Tags: java, image, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I need to encrypt an image of size 151*15 with RSA.

This is the java code to encrypt the image file

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
plaintext = time;
cipher = Cipher.getInstance('RSA');
keygen = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance('RSA');
keyPair = keygen.genKeyPair();
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate())

plaintextUnicodeVals = uint16(plaintext)
plaintextBytes = typecast(plaintextUnicodeVals, 'int8')
ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintextBytes);
```

this is the image file to be encrypted

[image]

I got the folllowing error

Java exception occurred:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 117 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

please give me the hint Or procedure so that i can approach in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see the value in an encrypting an image of text instead of just encrypting the text (which is obviously below 117 bytes). Could you enlighten me on that thought process?

Comment: Don't delete an re-ask a practically identical question.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I used matlab to read the image into matrix X.Its size is 151*15=2265.Then I transformed the matrix X  into row vector of 1*2265 ,which is time input in the given code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use AES for encrypting large data. RSA cannot encrypt data larger than key's size. 
So you can encrypt an AES key with RSA, and the whole image with AES (256 bit) (i.e. generate different AES key for each image).

Also RSA is very slow and thus is not good for encrypting large data, if you want to split up an image to a large number of blocks of size 117 bytes and encrypt them one by one.

---

For example:

```
  public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) {
    try {
        KeyPair keyPair = initalizeKeyPair();

        final javax.crypto.Cipher rsa = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsa.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        final byte[] secretKey = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(secretKey);

        final javax.crypto.Cipher aes = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES");
        aes.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);

        final byte[] ciphedKey = rsa.doFinal(secretKey);
        final byte[] ciphedData = aes.doFinal(data);

        byte[] result = new byte[256 + ciphedData.length];

        System.arraycopy(ciphedKey, 0, result, 0, 256);
        System.arraycopy(ciphedData, 0, result, 256, ciphedData.length);

        return result;
    } catch (... e) {
        throw new SomeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have to use RSA although it will take  time.This is a just a project to demonstrate.If you please tell me how to split image in java.

Comment: You need to build a List<byte[]> where each element consists of elements of size no longer than 117 bytes and then encrypt each one, and then concatenate them into a single byte[].
But believe me, this is overkill. Use AES: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard it's approved by US government and very secure.